# Matplotlib fill under and between surfaces

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, fill, surface

I managed to make my first graph with matplotlib but now I am stuck. I made a surface graph and I'm trying to figure out two things:

1) how do I fill color (shade) under the surface (between my surface and z=0 plane)?
2) is it possible to plot second and third surface one over another (and fill spaces between them with some color) - to create '3d stackplot'

My plot:
[image]

Comment: I like the sound of this idea, but in the end I'm not quite sure what it would mean. Are you looking into the volume? Or seeing a cross section? That is, when you fill between two lines in a 2D plot, you can see the entire area of the fill, every point, and it would, for example, give some idea of the area. But you can't do that with a volume. So what's your goal.

Comment: You're right - the issue will be that I will actually lose some information in the middle of the graph. In my case though, what counts is mainly the altitude of each point over the XY plane and creating the layers is suppose to just represent the fact, that 3 different sets of data contribute to the final result - it will be enough to see from the side that the graph has a few layers and the main information is just the altitude of each point.
Of course the ideal situation would be if I could just turn on and off each layer of the graph, but I have no idea if it's even possible.

Comment: This may be possible in matplotlib, but matplotlib doesn't have very powerful 3D graphics, so you'd be pushing the limits. You could probably do this (eg, insert a 2D plot for the fill). Have you thought of a more powerful 3D visualization tool, like VTK (see [Mayavi](https://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/))? If you can imagine it you can do it with VTK/Mayavi, although it has a **much** steeper learning curve.